# How to edit a xml file using powershell where it checks before line and edit the next line?

Tags: xml, powershell

```html
<distribution>
 <r>
  <type>Product</type>
  <name>TT3</name>
  <version>1.0.x</version>
  <revision></revision>
 </r>
 <r>
  <type>Module</type>
  <name>winner</name>
  <version>1.5.6</version>
  <revision>-1</revision>
 </r>
    </distribution>
```

where the powershell script should search for the TT3 in name and change the text for the next line version from 1.0.x to 2.0.x

Any code snippets please??

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't ask for code snippets if you haven't one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to iterate the distribution child nodes and update accordingly:

```
# Create XML object to load data into
$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument

# Load in XML file
$xml.Load("input.xml")

# Iterate each child node
foreach ($node in $xml.distribution.ChildNodes)
{
    # Check if name is equal to TT3 and update the version if it is
    if ($node.name -eq "TT3")
    {
        $node.version = "2.0.x"
    }
}

# Save to new XML file
# Safer since you don't corrupt original XML file
$xml.Save("output.xml")
```

**output.xml**

```
<distribution>
  <r>
    <type>Product</type>
    <name>TT3</name>
    <version>2.0.x</version>
    <revision></revision>
  </r>
  <r>
    <type>Module</type>
    <name>winner</name>
    <version>1.5.6</version>
    <revision>-1</revision>
  </r>
</distribution>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Any links or suggestions to increase my powershell script skills